# How to apply filter on list of _2 of tuples in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want all the lists(the first element of below tuple) if second element is the powers of 2. I am new to Scala and stuck with syntax. Could anyone help me here I want to apply filter on below code to get below output.

Output:

```
List(1,3)
List(1,7)
List(3,5)
List(7,9)
```

input:

```
scala> a.toList.combinations(2).map(x => (x, x.sum)).foreach(println)
(List(1, 3),4)
(List(1, 5),6)
(List(1, 7),8)
(List(1, 9),10)
(List(3, 5),8)
(List(3, 7),10)
(List(3, 9),12)
(List(5, 7),12)
(List(5, 9),14)
(List(7, 9),16)
```

Comment: You can use `foldLeft` for this. [Documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B)

Answer (score 0):

```
val tups = List((List(1, 3),4), (List(1, 5),6), (List(1, 7),8) , 
                (List(1, 9),10), (List(3, 5),8), (List(3, 7),10), 
                (List(3, 9),12), (List(5, 7),12),
                (List(5, 9),14), (List(7, 9),16))
```

Using `fold`:

```
tups.foldLeft(List[List[Int]]())((a, b) => if((b._2 & (b._2 - 1)) == 0) a :+ b._1 else a)
```

Using `filter` and `map`:

```
tups.filter(e => (e._2 & (e._2 - 1)) == 0).map(_._1)
```

`x & (x - 1) == 0` is the bitwise operation that checks if a number is a power of 2

For a more detailed explanation of the syntax, documentation for `fold` and other `List` operations can be found [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#foldLeft%5BB%5D(z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B)

Comment: I have of powerof2 function which returns boolean if its power of 2. but below command giving me an empty iterator. I am not sure where the error is. 

scala> var result  = b.filter(e => powerof2(e._2) == true).map(_._1)
result: Iterator[List[Int]] = empty iterator

Comment: Here is the function, def powerof2(n: Int): Boolean = {
if (n == 1) { return true }
else if (n % 2 != 0 | n == 0) { return false }
return powerof2( n/2) }

Comment: @Divi your function is wrong. This is very important, don't **ever** use `return` in Scala. You might think you need it, but you don't. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `.filter()` + `.map()` = `.collect{}`

Answer (score 0):

For

```
val xs = List(1,3,5,7,9)
```

another approach that incorporates the generation of input and corresponding filtering includes

```
import scala.math.log

// testPower true if log is integral value
// log_base n = log_e n / log_e base

def testPower(n: Int, base: Int = 2): Boolean = {
  val lg = log(n) / log(base)
  lg.toInt == lg 
}

xs.combinations(2).filter(ys => testPower(ys.sum)).toList
```

The test provided in @sinanspd answer is more succinct as well as more efficient; the test here generalises to any power in addition to 2. This solution works for any combination size as it sums up the entire combination (sub)list.

Comment: Thank you but it doesnt work if there are duplicates in array. Eg Array( 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 7). some function here just taking the disntincts not considering duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that the binary representation of an element that is the power of 2, has only 1 bit which is 1, and all. others are 0's. Then use `toBinaryString` method:

```
val xs = List(1, 3, 5, 7, 9).combinations(2).map(x => (x, x.sum)).toList
val result = xs.filter(_._2.toBinaryString.count(_ == '1') == 1).map(_._1)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bikcIC5nSLCFQUT5xeAV9Q).